# replace all font-size using javascript in IE

Tags: jquery

we need to replace all font size that has 100% with 1em like menntioned below. But the below code works in only chrome and not in IE. can you suggest generic way to replace all font size in all browsers.

```
var outerHTML = $('<div>').append($("svg").clone()).html();
outerHTML = outerHTML.replace(new RegExp('font-size:100%;', 'g'), 'font-size:1em;');
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery please add the tag to your question.

Comment: Did you try just changing the styles with `css()`, a regex seems highly inappropriate for this

Comment: You should remove the css from the code stored in outerHTML. Use a CSS stylesheet and you will be able to control, *without* javascript, the look of your page.

Comment: Why? Is the source unchangeable wherever it is physically stored? What you are doing is going to be extremely inefficient. I would try overriding the font size in a style-sheet or do as adaneo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Kind and simple solution. You should never have inline styles. Just put your styles in a css, and remove everything from your html. You´re mixing up the content layer with the presentation layer.

Removing all inline styles and putting them into a css stylesheet will allow you to gain more flexibility and mantainable code.

Regards.

Comment: This is somewhat true, but any manipulation of styles done with javascript will add inline styles, so there's no guarantee the OP manually added the styles, in fact I'd say it's more likely the SVG was created programatically

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion the best solution I would recommend, is using CSS.
- It is clean way doing it.
- It is never going to break your application (helps avoiding script errors)